# Mapping youtube_search hash results for listbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using [this](https://github.com/grosser/youtube_search) gem to search for youtube videos and display with ajax in a listbox. I want to get the title and video_id from the hash result but no idea how to do it. I've tried the code below but it shows `undefined method title for #<Hash:0x0000000582b270>`

This is my code, I want arrays of [:title, :video_id] so it can be displayed in the listbox. Thanks.

```
search_result = YoutubeSearch.search(params[:query])
render :json => search_result.map{|k,v| [k.title, v.video_id] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search method aparently returns an array of hashes of videos data, not only one.
And the way you get values from a hash is like this:

```
results = {}
search_result.each do |s|
  results[s['id']] = s['title']
end

puts results
```